# How to remove a subset of elements from an ordered double array in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How do remove a subset of elements from a double array in Matlab? The arrays are ordered and 1-dimensional.

For example, given

```
A=[1,3,5,6,7];
a=[3,6];
```

desire

```
A_a=[1,5,7];
```

If `a` was scalar, I can do `A_a=A(A~=a)`. How does it work if `a` is not scalar?

My concern with naïve looping around `A_a=A(A~=a(i))` is that, seemingly, for every element `a(i)`, a comparison is made for every element in `A`, which ignores the underlying order in the 2 arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

Here are several ways to do this:

1. Using `ismember` to create logical indexing:

```
A_a = A(~ismember(A, a))
```

2. Treat A and a as sets, and use `setdiff`

```
A_a = setdiff(A, a)</del>
```

- EDIT: Note that as [Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2586922/luis-mendo) pointed out, this will also remove duplicate values in A, which may not be desirable.

3. Use `arrayfun` to generate logical indices

```
A_a = A(arrayfun(@(x)~any(x==a), A))
```

4. Good old fashioned for loop

```
A_a = []
for element = A
    if ~any(a == element)
        A_a(end+1) = element ;
    end
end
```

Comment: Excellent answer. May I suggest a reverse for loop that **deletes** elements from `A_a = A` in addition to your for loop that adds elements to an empty `A_a`?

Comment: Depending on the relative lengths of A and a, doing OP’s `A_a=A(A~=a)` in a loop could be more efficient than #4. Still, the first two answers are the better solutions.

Comment: Note that `setdiff` will also remove duplicates from `A`

Comment: @Luis Good point, edited answer to note that.